# Different ways to define a function in Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin

I'm new at Kotlin, migrating from Java. One thing I think is a little bit confusing is the fact we may declare a function using different ways. Bellow are at least 3 ways to accomplish that:

```
package me.bruno.santana

class MyClass {

   fun square(number: Int) = number * number

   fun square2(number: Int): Int{
       return number * number
   }

}

fun MyClass.square3(number: Int) = number * number

fun main(){
   val obj = MyClass()
   println(obj.square(3))
   println(obj.square2(3))
   println(obj.square3(3))
}
```

What is the difference between this 3 ways in practical terms? I know the last one is related to extension funcion concept, but I don't know what it differs from the conventional way in practical terms.

Another thing is weird for me is the assignment in the function definition(using equals sign to associate the function's body to the function's signature). Is it in any way different from the convetional way using curly braces as in Java?

Thank you.

Comment: The equal sign is just a shorthand to avoid `return` and to allow the return type to be inferred automatically. The difference with the second one is only in the syntax. The last one is an extension function, it allows you to define a function for a class without declaring it the class.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Is there a preferable way to declare a function or It only depends on the programmer's personal preference?

Comment: It's considered more idiomatic to declare extension functions for utility functions (instead of `object Utils` for example), or when a function operates mainly on a specific class (For example `fun Dog.walk()` instead of `fun walk(dog: Dog)`). But it's pretty much up to you in the end.

Comment: @Nicolas I invite you to post a full answer.  (Comments are considered ephemeral on many StackExchange sites, while answers are eternal!  I'd post one, but I think you deserve the honour :-)  You could also mention that, in addition to being shorter, the `=` syntax for defining a function lets you leave the compiler to infer the type, which you can't do with the brace syntax.  So the `=` format is usually used for very short functions that return a (non-Unit) value.  But the end product is the same for both formats.

Answer (score 3):

## 1. This is single expression function:

- When a function returns a single expression, the curly braces can be omitted and the body is specified after a = symbol
- Explicitly declaring the return type is optional when this can be inferred by the compiler:

```kotlin
 fun square(number: Int) = number * number
```

## 2. This is normal function

That can have single-line or multi-lines and required return type (but `Unit` is optional):

```kotlin
fun square2(number: Int): Int {
    return number * number
}
```

## 3. This is Extension functions:

- Kotlin provides the ability to extend a class with new functionality without having to inherit from the class or use design patterns such as Decorator.
- Extensions are resolved statically: Extensions do not actually modify classes they extend. By defining an extension, you do not insert new members into a class, but merely make new functions callable with the dot-notation on variables of this type
- Often used to write utility functions and enhance readability via `dot-notation`.
- If an extension is declared outside its receiver type, such an extension cannot access the receiver's private members.

```kotlin
fun MyClass.square3(number: Int) = number * number
```

Answer (score 1):

To add something about extension functions: there are four common reasons to use them that I can think of.

- You don't control the source code of the class you're adding the function to.
- You want to add functions only to specifically typed instances of a class. For example, you could write a function for your `Foo<T: Animal>` class that is only available on instances that are a `Foo<Pet>`.
- You want to add something like a `final` function to an interface. This is used frequently in the standard library. If you define a function inside an interface, its behavior is unpredictable because interface functions cannot be final. By declaring it outside the interface as an extension, it can be hidden (by writing a different extension function with the same signature), but it cannot be overridden. Hiding it still requires the user to import the other version of the function, so it must be done explicitly.
- You want to confine the scope of the added function. Maybe the function only really makes sense in a certain context, so you don't want it to clutter the IDE auto-complete everywhere. Or maybe it uses a property of a certain class, so it must be defined within that class.

When you're just composing one of your own typical classes, you won't frequently need to use an extension function.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please exemplify the reasons three(final function to an interface) and four(confine the scope of the added function)? I didn't understand completely what you mean.

Comment: A final function is one that can not be overridden, which you might want to protect some behavior from being modified. Interfaces don’t support final functions, so you can use extension functions on the interface to get similar behavior as a final function.

Comment: It would be long winded to come up with an example of number 4 for one of your own classes. But suppose you had your own version of the String class. Maybe you want to write a function for it that parses it as a URL. You want this function to be available everywhere String is used, because you don’t always use a String as a URL. So you could make it an extension function so it is only available when using the String in certain classes.